# How to make long text accessible

Tags: ios, text, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to make my app more accessible but I have a problem. Part of my app consists of pieces of advice, each composed of an `UIScrollView` with long text. (The text is a `UIImage` I prepared with Photoshop ).

I would like to make it accessible so that the users could listen to all the advice and pause it whenever they want. I thought of using `UIAccessibilityLabel` but the text is too long.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Let me preface this by saying I am not an iOS developer but am a long time blind iOS user.

There is no way to easily pause the reading of text and resume at the exact same spot that I know of. According to the documentation, I've found `accessibilityLabel` is meant to provide accessibility information that can be conveyed in under a sentence. An option I can think of would be to test whether VoiceOver is enabled using `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning`. If this is true, you could put your text into a text view, and display that instead of your `UIImage`.

A `textView` will allow a VoiceOver user to read the text by character, word, or line, which is the best option available. If VoiceOver isn’t running, your test will return false, the `UIImage` will be displayed as normal, and the user won’t see anything different.